# Call Javascript functions in succession

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

**Goal:** I am trying to create a slightly dynamic page animated with basic canvas animations using `setInterval()`. When the user first goes to the page, a background image displays. Then a canvas appears over it and gradually the opacity increases to completely opaque black. After the canvas is black, I want white text to appear over my black canvas.

**Problem:** The canvas transition and the text appear at the same time.

I have researched this issue, and there appears to be a panoply of solutions here. I have already tried many variations in my own code. Once I had two separate functions. Another time I tried calling a function which then called both functions in succession. I read a blog about creating an array of functions, and then looping through the functions. That idea is intriguing, but I am wondering if there is something much more simple here that will suffice.

I was working with it on jsfiddle, but the website is not cooperating at the moment. So here is what I have right now:

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#" id="LftButton"><img src="imageFiles/arrowButtonLft.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" id="RtButton"><img src="imageFiles/arrowButtonRt.png" /></a>
    <div id="canvasWrapper">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="675" height="600">
            <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
        </canvas>
        <script src="aboutMeScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
</div>

#myCanvas{
width:675px;
height:600px;
float:left;
}
#canvasWrapper{
width:675px;
height:600px;
margin:auto;
}
#RtButton{
    float:right;
margin-right:34px;
}
#LftButton{
    float:left;
margin-left:34px;
}
#RtButton, #LftButton{
margin-top:200px;
}

var drawing = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
//Initialize drawing context
var ctx = drawing.getContext("2d");
//Canvas commands follow
var alphaCounter = .033;

function fadeCanvas(){
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0," + alphaCounter + ")";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,675,600);
alphaCounter += .03;
}
function display411(){
ctx.fillStyle=('#fff');
ctx.font='bold 14px + "Courier New, Courier, monospace" +';
ctx.fillText('Click the arrow keys forward to reveal the bigger picture.', 100,100);
}
function init(){
setInterval(fadeCanvas,100);
ctx.save();
setTimeout(display411(), 5000)
}
window.onload = init();
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What's wrong with the array of functions?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. I was actually hoping there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Looping through an array is fairly simple. :)

Comment: I am looking for the correct syntax to use an array to call a method. Firebug is telling me that array[i]() is not a method. Can you give me a hint about where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.
1. as another commentor has mentioned, your setTimeout call was incorrect
2. Even if you correct the setTimeout call, the fadeCanvas() interval will immediately overwrite whatever text you display.

In my opinion, the best approach is to test for 100% opacity within fadeCanvas(), and once that goal is reached, clear the interval and call display411() directly.

```
function fadeCanvas(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0," + alphaCounter + ")";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,675,600);
    alphaCounter += .03;
    if (alphaCounter >= 1) {
        clearInterval(fadeToBlack);
        display411();
    }
}

function init(){
    fadeToBlack = setInterval(fadeCanvas,100);
    ctx.save();
    //setTimeout(display411(), 5000) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(display411(), 5000)
window.onload = init();
```

You are *executing* the functions directly then and there, when you just want to *pass* them around. Get rid of the `()`:

```
setTimeout(display411, 5000);
window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple setup (it's perhaps a bit complex for this simple task, but you can reuse the pattern, and/or abstract it, if you need more effects)

```
function fadeBlack(callback) {
  var timer,
      context = getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d"),
      opacity = 0;

  function step() {
    opacity += 0.03;
    context.fillStyle "rgba(0,0,0," + opacity + ")";
    context.fillRect(0,0,675,600);
    if( opacity >= 1 ) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      if( typeof callback === "function" ) {
        callback();
      }
    }
  }

  setInterval(step, 100);
}

fadeBlack(function() {
  var context = getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");
  context.fillStyle = '#fff';
  context.font      = 'bold 14px + "Courier New, Courier, monospace" +';
  context.fillText('Click the arrow keys forward to reveal the bigger picture.', 100,100);
});
```

When `fadeBlack` completes, it calls the `callback`, which - in this case - draws the text